# jquery post php undefined index

Tags: php, ajax, post

This is my html with script

```
<div id="info" class="container-fluid">Here is some text</div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post("testPHP.php", {name: "John"}, function(data)
    {
        $( "#info" ).html( data )
    })
</script>
```

and the php code

```
<?php
   $name=$_POST['name']; 
   echo $name;
?>
```

In html I may see the name John displayed in the div with id info.
But when I run the php file I get this error

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\ticketing\testPHP.php
>   on line 2

How can I send a variable via Ajax to a php file and echo this?

Comment: Is this one file or two separate files? You should have 2 files and you don't need to run the php file, only call it using `$.post()`.

Comment: But.. You're already sending variables (`name`) with AJAX to a PHP file.. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Ajax in pass some extra data like **type:"ajax"**
and file in check

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type']=='ajax') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $name;
} else {
echo "You access with direct URL";
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if there is a post request in your testPHP.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo $name;
} else {
    // do something else here
}
```

Comment: I tired this and I get this error   Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\ticketing\testPHP.php on line 3  What I want to do is to have an <a> tag like this:    <a href='testPHP.php'>view ticket</a> in the html file and when click to the link and redirect to testPHP.php , I want to echo the name variable.

Comment: I edited the answer, try again. If you get error please paste the error message.

Comment: Now I get "You access with direct URL" in both html and php file. This is my html code:                                                                                      <div id="info" class="container-fluid">Here is some text</div>
<a href='testPHP.php'>view ticket</a>                                                 The idea is that when click on the link and redirect to testPHP.php I want the variable name to be echoed I have modified the script like this: $('a').click(function()
 {
 $.post("testPHP.php", {name: "John"}, function(data)
  {
   $( "#info" ).html( data )
  })
 })

Answer (score 0):

It won't send any data because there is no form in it. No object will be serialized(input, select, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This should be a comment, not an answer. You can [leave a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) once you [earn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).